# Shell scripting - spaces in variables?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, whitespace

Here's the problem I have with my bash script:

```
    date1=(`date -d @$startdate`)
    date2=(`date -d @$enddate`)

    touch --date="$date1" /tmp/newerthan
    touch --date="$date2" /tmp/olderthan
```

Since the words returned by the `date -d` command contain spaces, the only thing that gets processed by the `touch --date="$var"` command is the first word (which is "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"... etc), so it doesn't work properly.

How can I work around this problem and be able to get the subsequent lines to process the entire string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used an array assignment in:

```
date1=(`date -d @$startdate`)
```

Either use plain backquotes (definitely not the preferred technique, though):

```
date1=`date -d @$startdate`
```

Or (much better) use `$(...)`:

```
date1=$(date -d @$startdate)
```

Or, at a pinch (there'd have to be a good reason), use this to copy the whole array into the argument to `touch`:

```
touch --date="${date1[*]}" /tmp/newerthan
```

You might want to consider double quotes around `@$startdate`, too.